# El dato date no se muestra bien en la aplicación

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, api, app

El valor "created_at" no se muestra bien en la aplicación, que es lo que está mal? Lo que yo hago es enviarle los datos de esta forma con Laravel:

```
 $jsonAlerts = new JsonAlerts();
 $jsonAlerts->alerts = array();
 $count = 0;
 foreach($alerts as $alert){
     ++$count;
     $newAlert = new JsonAlert();
     $newAlert->idAlert = $alert->idAlert;
     $newAlert->created_at = $alert->created_at;  // Dato que se ve mal en la APP, se ve la fecha pero la hora se muestra como un punto . este valor es un TIMESTAMP en la DB
     $newAlert->comment = $alert->comment;
     ...[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
     array_push($jsonAlerts->alerts, $newAlert);
 }

 return response(json_encode($jsonAlerts), 200) // Envío del dato
   ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
   ->header('Content-Length', $count);
```

Con el Rest client de Chrome para realizar pruebas con Apis se muestran los datos de la imagen:

¿Que pasa y como se soluciona? Saludos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿cuál es el código que imprime dicha información?

Comment: Solucionado: Por lo visto a veces envía un \n primero y otras no... Ni idea de porque ocurre esto pero es cosa del Laravel seguro, me ha pasado dos veces este mes, no se que puede ser...

Answer (score 1):

En el caso de que `created_at` sea una instancia de `Carbon`
Enviá solo la fecha en lugar del timestamp

```
$newAlert->created_at = $alert->created_at->format('Y-m-d');
```

Sino podes crear la instancia de `Carbon` haciendo

```
// Forma 1
\Carbon\Carbon::create($newAlert->created_at)->format('Y-m-d');  

// Forma 2
\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:m:s',$newAlert->created_at)->format('Y-m-d');
```